# How to get string value of token in flex and bison?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I have this token in my .lex file:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+    { yylval = yytext; return ALPHANUM; }
```

and this code in my .y file:

```
Sentence: "Sphere(" ALPHANUM ")."
{
FILE* file = fopen("C:/test.txt", "a+");
char st1[] = "polySphere -name ";
strcat(st1, $2);
strcat(st1, ";");
fprintf(file,"%s", st1);
fclose(file);
}
```

I get this error when I try to compile:

warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

So $2 is an int, how do I make it a string?

For example: "Sphere(worldGlobe)." I want $2 to have the string value worldGlobe here.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show us your union declaration from the .y file and your token declaration for ALPHANUM from the .y file?

Comment: Assuming you have multiple yylval types. If all you ever return is char* then you should have `#define YYSTYPE char*` in the prologue part of the .y file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the absence of a `%union` declaration, bison defines `YYSTYPE` to be int, so all of the
symbol values are integers.
In fact you have a few solutions for this problem:

**1) yylval|union solution (RECOMMENDED):**
 
As you may know yylval is a global variable used by the lexer to store yytext variable (`yylval = yytext;`) so you should tell your lexer which types you would to store.you can simply add this line to the header of your YACC grammar:

```
#define YYSTYPE char *
```

you will store here only string values.

By the way if you want to store different types you should specify in your yacc file:

```
%union {
    char *a;
    double d;
    int fn;
}
```

then in your lex you will have

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+    { **yylval.a** = yytext; return ALPHANUM; }
```

**2) Using yytext:**

Advice: for callbacks after rules in yacc i,personally prefer to use functions. not the whole code as you do :)

this solution is really simple .
`Sentence: "Sphere("{callback_your_function(yytext);} ALPHANUM ")."`

the **yytext** here will have the value of your ALPHANUM token because it's the next token.

Comment: I'd be careful sticking the raw yytext pointer into the yylval. Next time you lex something, the buffer is overwritten. It's not a suitable approach if you have a parser that will collect several such tokens into a rule and you refer to them with $1, $2, at the same time. It may be okay if you're just calling yylex() in a loop and processing tokens one by one.