# Warning : assignment makes integer from pointer without cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers, casting, warnings

There is a warning that I could not get rid of it from this code. And this is the code that I could provide :

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

[1-9]+          {
                        yylval.iVal = atoi(yytext);
                        printf("NUMBER\n");
                        return NUMBER;
                }
[a-z]           {
                        printf("VARIABLE\n");
                        yylval.cVal = yytext;
                        return VARIABLE;
                }
[-()<>=+/*\n]   {
                        printf("OPERATOR\n");
                        return *yytext;
                 }
"^"             {
                        printf("POW\n");
                        return *yytext;
                }
[ \t]+          ;      // Skip whitespaces.
.               yyerror("Unknown character.\n");

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
     return 1;
}
```

I got the warning on this part : `yylval.cVal = yytext;`. How could it go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you set cVal to in the union?

Comment: What type is `yylval.cVal`?  How were we supposed to guess that?  The trouble is that the types of `yylval.cVal` and `yytext` are not compatible.  Since `yytext` is either an array or a pointer (so on the RHS of an assignment, it is treated as a pointer either way), presumably `yylval.cVal` is a non-pointer type.  Maybe you wanted `yylval.cVal = yytext[0];`?  Or maybe you really need to duplicate the string and fix the type of `yylval.cVal`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get string value of token in flex and bison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632516/how-to-get-string-value-of-token-in-flex-and-bison)

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information<sup>(a)</sup> in the question to be certain but you're getting a message that normally involves assigning a pointer to an integral type, along with the following information:

| regex | field | likely type based on other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [1-9]+ | iVal | int |
| [a-z] | cVal | char |

That means the `yytext` variable (`char *`) is being directly assigned to `cVal` a (very likely) `char` variable.

The best way to fix this is simply get the first character from the memory pointed to by `yytext`, so that it is the correct type. That would be something like:

```c
yylval.cVal = *yytext; // or yytext[0]
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The type of `yytext` can be inferred by the fact you're doing `atoi()` on it successfully. The type of `yylval.cVal` is not provided but is likely to be `char` given the `iVal/cVal` naming.

It's also *very* common practice to use `yylval` as a union which can contain various parameter types when parsing computer languages, as you appear to be doing here.